# Nodal analysis with LEDs

Tags: circuit-analysis, led, nodal-analysis

How does nodal analysis work if I have not only resistors but also LEDs in my circuit?

Do I then have to convert the LEDs to resistors somehow?

Comment: You assume a suitable model for making the calculations. What kind of system you have?

Comment: For basic KVL and KCL, assume that the LED is a voltage source. The voltage will vary with the color of the LED and the current, so this will be an approximation. For a basic LED, the voltage drop is reasonably constant from about 2 to 10 mA. One of the contributers here has a nice page. http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/

Comment: @Mattman944 Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends at which level of accuracy you want to carry out your analysis.

If by "nodal analysis" you mean "linear nodal analysis", the thing they usually teach at undergraduate EE level, you have to substitute the LED with a suitable ***linear model*** made up of resistors and voltage sources (there are also different linear models depending on the level of accuracy you need).

Since the specific model is also dependent on where the operating point of the diode lies on the [diode characteristic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Current%E2%80%93voltage_characteristic), i.e. it depends on whether the diode is in forward conduction region (diode is ON), in cut-off region (diode is OFF) or in reverse conduction region (diode is in breakdown), *you have to verify your assumptions after you've solved your equation system*.

For example, you begin by an educated guess for your **red LED** to be ON, you substitute it with a voltage source \$V_{LED}\$ of about 1.8V (positive terminal where the anode of the diode was), then you write the linear equations system and solve it.

When you have your solutions, you check that the diode is actually ON by checking that the current through your equivalent voltage source \$V_{LED}\$ is in the right direction, i.e. from anode (positive terminal) to cathode. If yes, that's the solution. If not, you have to change your assumptions and repeat the analysis with a different model (e.g. the diode is OFF and you substitute it with an open circuit).

OTOH, if you need more precision, such as is the case with SPICE simulators, you have to use the [Shockley diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation) and build a non-linear equations system and use a suitable algorithm to solve it, usually numerically, such as [the Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Systems_of_equations) (that's what SPICE simulators more or less do).